# How to test whether a chat program uses any outside servers when downloaded?

Tags: php, mysql, chat

I am supposed to use a chat file on a website on a private server that does not rely on any outside server support or connections. I found this free chat script ( http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/script-chat-simple_s2 ) but I am not sure if it uses any outside connections. So this is my question: is there a way to tell/test whether a script like this uses any outside servers?

Sorry but my exp-expertise on php and mysql is very limited.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: run it over a lan that is not connected to the internet? If it works then maybe it doesn't use any external server?

Comment: How would I do that? is there a simpler way?

Comment: wireshark or other network monitoring software can tell you that, or you can just disconnect from the interwebs :) and test it.

Comment: Load it in a Docker container.

Comment: When I disconnect from the internet it doesn't show the chatbox.  Nonetheless, it shows use of javascript in the index page <div id="chatzone" data-style="auto"></div>..... <script type="text/javascript" src="chatfiles/chatfunctions.js"></script>